# Google Sheets API Reverse Order Parameter Ignored

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the `Google Sheets API` and trying to get the results in reverse order, but it seems to be ignoring the reverse parameter.

**Should be in reverse order**

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xme2djjjb9IM6OW_T7tVXSm9UHNAvEKBn1kLEVT5HkY/od6/public/full?reverse=true

**Should be in normal order**

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1xme2djjjb9IM6OW_T7tVXSm9UHNAvEKBn1kLEVT5HkY/od6/public/full?reverse=false

This is a link to the public Google Spreadsheet so you can see how it looks as standard on Google's web UI:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xme2djjjb9IM6OW_T7tVXSm9UHNAvEKBn1kLEVT5HkY/

**Google's Documentation**

As far as I can see, according to Google's documentation, this should work fine. Am I missing something blindingly obvious or is sorting on the Sheets API broken at the moment?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sorting_rows_1

> Sorting rows
>
> By default, rows in the list feed appear in the same order as the
>   corresponding rows in the user-interface; that is, they're in order by
>   row number.
>
> To get rows in reverse order, send the following request, using the
>   reverse query parameter to specify the sort order.
>
> GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/key/worksheetId/private/full?reverse=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3588) for more information or to track when it is resolved.

Comment: Nice... issue for over a year! Thanks for the link and answer, at least it's not me doing something wrong. I've just reversed the results manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works if you set `orderby` parameter, e.g. `?orderby=column:date&reverse=true`.
Although I couldn't get it to work with ordering by row number.

By searching [GData Java Client repo](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client) I found that ordering by row number is done by setting `orderby=position`, but that didn't work.

So if you need to sort by row number, then your best bet is manual sorting and `start-index`/`max-results` parameters.